# Project is empty after restarting Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is what happened after Android Studio Crashed and I opened it again:

[image]

Literally nothing appeared. I tried restarting it, but to no avail. Any idea how to fix this? I also can't seem to rebuild/sync my gradle as it doesn't give me the option.

Comment: Relaunched after updating? Check if you have your project files at the location. If yes then something's wrong with the studio. Try reopening the project and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: I just checked my project files through my file explorer; the file is still there but I lost all my src code. I think I'm gonna jump of a bridge

Comment: Just for the future: that's why you should use version control. Many free options exist, for example GitHub.

Comment: Yeah haha, I learned my lesson

Comment: open your settings.gradle file located in root directory and see your app is including or not. you can also see your file by selectting project or project file ,option in top left corner dropdown where android is showing. send screenshot after this.